# Perform custom actions on Cypress test retry

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am using retries in my Cypress test. Every time a test is retried, I want to perform an action (e.g. log details about the failure in a file).

I thought the `command:retry` from [the catalog of events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Cypress-Events) might be useful, but I am not sure what does the parameter mean and how can I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find `command:retry` is a bit too granular, try the [on fail](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Catching-Test-Failures) event.

```js
Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
  debugger
  
  // take a look at the parameters
  console.log('error', error.message)
  console.log('runnable', runnable)

  // for example
  let currentTest = runnable.ctx.currentTest
  let title = runnable.title

  throw error // throw error to have test still fail
})
```

---

**About retries**

The runnable object passed to the on('fail') event has a couple of properties giving useful info about the retries.

Say you set `{retries: 2}` on the the test, the fail event is called for every attempt that fails.

On the first & second run, `runnable.final === false`.

On the third and last attempt, `runnable.final === true` plus `runnable.prevAttempts` has an array of the previous two (failed) attempts.

I haven't checked out what you get if, say, the third attempt passes.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for an event that would only execute after test is retried. But after thinking this through, it may be enough to use the on fail event.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [cyclope](https://github.com/bahmutov/cyclope) plugin that may be covering what you are wanting to do with test failures. This plugin includes a utilty function `savePageIfTestFailed`, which you can call in an `afterEach()` inside your `support/index.js` file.